# Looking to set a formula for date to be added if adjacent cell is filled in

Tags: date, google-sheets, formulas

I am building a simple spreadsheet where I want to have column A fill in the date when column B is filled in.

I have built it into a excel spreadsheet but when uploading it, I lost that and can not figure out how to get this done in Sheets.

I posted this in google sheets community and was told to post it here

Comment: I think you have to post it to superuser.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Comment: @pnuts yes superuser is the site for these kinds of questions:)

Comment: You mean the subject and topic or the format of the question? I think this question is on-topic in superuser. however it's not well formatted as a question and requires editing.

Comment: @pnuts what kind of question is super user for then?I believe he wants to use the google spreadsheet software like a power user.

Comment: Try this: [https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4737-google-sheet-auto-update-date.html]